# Right foot symbolism in Pacific Rim

Tags: pacific-rim, symbols

In *Pacific Rim*, there seems to be a recurrent motif of the right foot.

First, Mako loses her right shoe when she is a child, and is shown running with only her left shoe. Her adoptive father, Stacker Pentecost, later gives her this shoe as a symbol of trust.

Later, Hannibal Chau gets swallowed by a baby Kaiju, and loses his very distinctive right shoe in the process. In fact, the character is first introduced in the movie by his shoes. In a post-credit scene, we see that he survived and ask for his shoe.

Finally, in the final battle, the Gipsy Danger gets its right leg badly damaged

Have any of the creators commented on this apparent obsession with (right) feet?

Comment: I'm looking for evidence from EPs/Cast, but the expression, 'put your best foot forward' comes to mind. I haven't seen PR, but perhaps this motif plays to the moral philosophy of the work??

Comment: It doesn't really seem to fit. Narratively, it seems to go more with a moment were the characters are powerless

Comment: Ya, just thinking that that phrase would lend itself to oppoiste too, putting your worst foot forward and the consequences of that--but, again I didn't see the film, so I'm sure you're right. It was just a guess on my part.

Comment: So two people lost their right shoe, are you sure the motif isn't about left shoes, since they're the ones left?

Comment: In all seriousness though, this is quite light on establishing whether there even _is_ a motif, and you might be disappointed to find out that there probably _isn't_ one.

Comment: Possible, but that's also why I ask the question =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is unlikely to be any intentional motif or significance behind this. The Director, Guillermo del Toro, has explicitly stated that he intentionally avoided all inspirations.

> I felt there was a chance to do something fresh, something new that at the same time was conscious of the heritage, but not a pastiche or an homage or a greatest hits of everything. **One of the first things I did is make it a point to not check any old movies or any other references.** Like start from scratch.
>   <sub>[Guillermo del Toro in an interview](https://screenrant.com/guillermo-del-toro-pacific-rim-japan-anime/)</sub>

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

There does not appear to be any significance with the right foot in Japanese culture (though I'm american, so take that with a grain of salt). Nor in Mexican culture (Guillermo del Toro is Mexican). So there does not appear to be any subconscious reason for unshoeing/destroying right feet either.

All in all, it appears that this is simply a coincidence.